# GROUP BY not returning correct results

Tags: mysql

This query

```
SELECT releases.id,releases.label_no_country,releases.date 
FROM releases 
INNER JOIN labels_user_has_recd luhr 
ON luhr.label=releases.label_no_country 
WHERE luhr.user='Si Quick' 
GROUP BY releases.id 
HAVING datediff(now(),releases.date) < 90 
ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

gives

```
id  label_no_country    date
605639  Church  2016-04-28
595303  Uncanny Valley  2016-04-21
605806  Dekmantel   2016-04-21
607276  Uncanny Valley  2016-04-21
604280  Delsin  2016-04-21
598653  Another Picture     2016-04-21
605016  Skylevel    2016-04-20
606342  Retreat     2016-04-14
599363  Frank Music     2016-04-12
599320  Spazio Disponibile  2016-04-08
```

I would like to not return any duplicates in column `label_no_count` (i.e. not `Uncanny Valley` twice.

I have tried using `GROUP BY` in the following query

```
SELECT releases.id,releases.label_no_country,releases.date 
FROM releases 
INNER JOIN labels_user_has_recd luhr 
ON luhr.label=releases.label_no_country 
WHERE luhr.user='Si Quick' 
GROUP BY releases.label_no_country 
HAVING datediff(now(),releases.date) < 90 
ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

but this only returns one result, rather than removing duplicates

```
id  label_no_country    date
599320  Spazio Disponibile  2016-04-08
```

Comment: There's no aggregating function here, so GROUP BY serves no purpose. And decorum prevents me from saying what I think about providing a result set with no dataset

Comment: Didn't feel it needed a dataset as it was most likely going to be an error in the query...as proven by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `HAVING` to `WHERE` condition like

```
WHERE datediff(now(),releases.date) < 90
```

Your query should be

```
SELECT releases.id,releases.label_no_country,releases.date 
FROM releases 
INNER JOIN labels_user_has_recd luhr 
ON luhr.label=releases.label_no_country 
WHERE luhr.user='Si Quick'
AND datediff(now(),releases.date) < 90  
GROUP BY releases.label_no_country 
ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```